# When do we say "Alenu L'shabe'ach"?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, aleinu-leshabeiach

What are all the times when we say the *t'fila* beginning with the words "עלינו לשבח" commonly known as "Alenu"?

Clearly, saying it at the conclusion of things is a theme. But hopefully more specificity can be deduced from consideration of all of its recitals. As @Dave pointed out, its original placement within the *amida* of Rosh Hashana was not the conclusion of a service, but the conclusion of a subsection thereof.

Comment: Strictly speaking, some of these are mutually exclusive. For example (as far as I know this is true in all nuschaos), Aleinu is not said after Shacharis on a day when Musaf is said.

Comment: The same goes for מנחה and נעילה. But that is OK. They still both belong on the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some!

For Nusach Ashkenaz:

- At the end of *shacharis* (when there's no *mussaf*)
- At the end of *mincha*
- At the end of *ma'ariv*
- At the end of *mussaf*
- At the end of *kidush l'vana*
- At a *b'ris*
- *Shemoneh Esrei* of *mussaf* on *Rosh Hashanah*
- *Shemoneh Esrei* of *mussaf* on *Yom Kippur*

For Nusach Chabad:

- All of the above (except, perhaps, after a bris: it's not official Chabad minhag to say Aleinu then, and I haven't seen it done, although I understand that some Chabad communities do so)
- At the end of *n'ila*
- After *birkas hachama*

For Sephardim:

- At the end of shacharit (when there's no Mussaf)
- At the end of mincha
- At the end of arvit
- At the end of mussaf (even on Yom Kippur)
- Shemoneh Esrei of Mussaf on Rosh Hashanah
- Shemoneh Esrei of Mussaf on Yom Kippur

Comment: Who says it at the end of Ne'ilah? I think that's a *distinctly* Chabad minhag.

Comment: @Chanoch: indeed, R' Yehoshua Mondshine, in his collection of Chabad minhagim, comments that he hasn't found any other community that does so.

Comment: Saying Alenu at KL and a Bris is true when they are said as part of the recent prayer service (ex. after Kaddish Shalem, like Sefirat HaOmer), not if Alenu was already said after the service before those activities.

Comment: Don't forget that we don't say aleinu after any daytime (read: not Maariv) tefillos on YK.

Answer (score 3):

In the Shemoneh Esrei of Mussaf on Rosh Hashanah. If I'm not mistaken, that is where the tefillah was originally established (see [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95)).

Comment: According to this, you are not mistaken: http://books.google.com/books?id=o7w2v9XT3Y0C&pg=RA2-PA88&lpg=RA2-PA88&dq=aleinu+rosh+hashanah&source=bl&ots=sPrzaGi_T5&sig=xi6kIOKhHpm8ZywYq7cFblJOUUo&hl=en&ei=-JTyTKL6L8OclgfMgIWzDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CCYQ6AEwBTgU#v=onepage&q=aleinu%20rosh%20hashanah&f=false

Comment: WAF, I just added a link; your comment beat me by 2 seconds!

Comment: Also in the Musaf of Yom Kippur.

Comment: @Alex, but I think its inclusion in Rosh Hashana davening came first.

Comment: True. I just meant that it should be added to your list in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

For sepharadim:

- At the end of *shacharit* (when there's no Mussaf)
- At the end of *mincha*
- At the end of *arvit*
- At the end of *mussaf* (even on Yom Kippur)
- Shemoneh Esrei of Mussaf on Rosh Hashanah
- Shemoneh Esrei of Mussaf on Yom Kippur

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on when your finish your tefillah.

If one were to daven shacharit at netz and the mussaf at chatzot (which is the theoretical ideall, at least for a yachid and on a day like rosh chodesh where there is no issue of seudah; see the first biur halacha in 286) then he should say aleinu after shacharit and again after mussaf. Similarly, if mincha and maariv are being recited back to back then no aleinu should be said just like how we omit it from most prayers on Yom Kippur.

See [Mishna Brura 132 sk 7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=27)

Comment: Is your citation also supposed to be for the mussaf comment? If so, I'm not seeing it.